# Convert Textbox value to Integer

Tags: vb.net, casting, textbox, integer

I have the following Integer variables

```
Dim sMaxAmount As Integer
Dim sMinAmount As Integer
```

I am trying to compare them with a TextBox field.

```
If (Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionAmount) < sMinAmount And Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionAmount) > sMaxAmount) Then
```

Although I am converting it to `Integer` I get exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: use `txtTransactionAmount.Text` instead of `txtTransactionAmount`

```
If (Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionAmount.Text) < sMinAmount AndAlso Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionAmount.Text) > sMaxAmount)
```

Comment: Should use `AndAlso` instead of `And` as well

Answer (score 1):

`Val(TextBox.Text)` will convert the value of a TextBox to an Integer.

````vb
txtTotal.text= Val(txtPrice.text) * Val(txtQuantity.text)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not using the Text property to get the string contained in the TextBox, there are two other problems with your code.

1. You are not validating the contents of the TextBox. If the user enters something that can't be converted to an integer, an exception will be thrown.
2. The test you are doing doesn't make sense given the names of the variables. The value in the TextBox can't be **both** less than the minimum and more than the maximum.

The following code uses [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate the contents of the TextBox and convert it to an Integer. It also checks that the value in greater than or equal to `sMinAmount` and less than or equal to `sMaxAmount`.

```
Dim amount As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(txtTransactionAmount.Text, amount) _
  AndAlso amount >= sMinAmount AndAlso aamount <= sMaxAmount Then
    'The Integer called "amount" now contains a value between sMinAmount and sMinAmount
End If
```